# Quit a specflow scenario, or avoid execution based on a precondition

Tags: specflow, execution

I want to be able to avoid a specflow scenario execution, or quit at the first step, depending on external configuration. Is that possible?

Like
Background:
Given we have a satisfied precondition

the precondition fails and the scenario stops without returning an error

Answer (score 1):

If a step does not throw an exception, then the step passes. You could refactor that particular step into a private method, then simply wrap the method call in a try-catch inside an if statement:

```cs
[Given(@"we have a satisfied precondition")]
public void GivenWeHaveASatisfiedPrecondition()
{
   if (/* check your external config here */)
   {
      try
      {
         PerformPrecondition();
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
         Console.WriteLine("Step failed, but continuing scenario." + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + ex);
      }
   }
   else
   {
      // Failure in this step should fail the scenario.
      PerformPrecondition();
   }
}

private void PerformPrecondition()
{
   // Your step logic goes here
}
```

You haven't specified where your external configuration is at, but there are a thousand ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

IUnitTestRuntimeProvider interface should be injected
https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Execution/SkippingScenarios.html

however, I then run into the fact that this interface can not be resolved
https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow/issues/2076
the resolution of this does not work for me in a .Net 5, XUnit project, with Visual Studio 2019

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.